# how can i make uniqueness in existing oracle sql table if all columns are nullable and also not creating unique index but i can add constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, unique

i have an sql table , all columns are nullable , i need to make uniqueness for this table is there any way to be able to do that ? i can not create unique index , but i can add constraint

i have checked columns for all but i could not find unique column

Answer (score 2):

[Alter the table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html) and add a unique constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column_name);
```

Or, if you want a composite unique key:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column1, column2, columnN);
```

*Note: a unique constraint is backed by a unique index; so if you can create  a unique constraint then you should also be able to create a unique index.*

---

However, if you are asking how to make a table with duplicate rows unique by deleting the duplicate rows then:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY -- list all your columns
             column1, column2, /*...*/ columnN
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
         ) As rn
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID AND src.rn > 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET column1 = column1
  DELETE WHERE 1 = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wSYoUc3U)